# PowerShell initializes my loops at +1 of my specified initializer. Why?

Tags: powershell

```
for ($q = 0; $q -lt 3; $q++) {
    Write-Host $q
}
```

outputs:

```
1
2
```

But I was expecting to start at 0 because `$q = 0`:

```
0
1
2
```

Is this expected behavior or am I missing something extremely obvious?

Comment: I get 0,1,2 on PowerShell V2.0. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using PowerGUI script editor v 3.5.0.2293. I tried the same code in a regular console and it behaves as expected...

Comment: I am getting `0 1 2` using your same code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Stanley, I am using version 2.0 of PowerShell

Comment: Sounds like a bug in PowerGUI

Comment: I've tested it on same version of PowerGUI and I'm getting `0 1 2`

Comment: I just updated to the latest PowerGUI, 3.6.0.21, and it's working fine. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in PowerGui version 3.5.0.2293. Updating to the latest version resolves the bug.